# Address vs Solve in the context

Tags: verbs, differences

[The article "Jaw Implant"](http://www.cosmeticsurgerytoday.com/jaw-implant/)

> Fortunately, plastic surgery **solves the lack** of a properly sized jaw with the use of jaw implants, which augment the look of a patient’s jaw to create the proper proportions needed to have a beautiful face.

As the dictionaries state, "address" means that one begins to deal with a problem while "solve" indicates the removal of a problem.

If I changed "solve" to "address", how would the sense change in this text? Can't they be interchangeable here?

Comment: You can solve a problem but I don't think you can solve a lack. You can address a lack.

Comment: @chasly from UK  The Internet is full of examples containing "solve the/a lack", The Google gives 48, 400, 000 examples for "solve the lack of".

Comment: The internet is full of all sorts of nonsense. Perhaps Google ngram gives a more accurate picture. https://goo.gl/NqsbXF  The use of 'solve' does show up but usually in a very jargon way.

Comment: My suggestion is "Overcome the lack" https://goo.gl/ogQhGB

Answer (score 2):

Chasly from UK makes a good point. Most commonly, you would:

***"solve"*** a **problem**,

***"address"*** an **issue**, and,

***"compensate"*** for **a 'lack'**. (US)

Comment: Well, "compensate for"  beats my version "overcome" by a considerable margin! ---> https://goo.gl/yNJA08

Comment: +1 but I think that there’s a subtle distinction with  *compensate for* that implies a *workaround* whereas OP”a usage clearly implies *modification* to eliminate the problem.